# Where is this undefined coming from?

Tags: html, css, undefined

Currently have this online:
http://auxproducts.comuv.com/david/

But whenever I shrink the site (try yourself) there appears a top bar saying undefined

(screen: http://gyazo.com/b4982cfc77814253564a6b82f199dda6)

It's is 100% NOWHERE in my html. 100%, even if it says in the element inspect, it is not 100%.

Does someone may be know the solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you click in Chrome "Inspect element" to your "undefined" you can see, that it is some kind of title which you probably forget to specify in your javascript.

Comment: I have a feeling you're working on live. Right now you have resources missing, and syntax errors to boot.

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Comment: maybe somewhere in util.js (missing configvalue) or some other library like stickyheader.js...also fix the console errors, maybe this helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

Line 51 of your main.js:

```
$(
    '<div id="titleBar">' +
    '<a href="#navPanel" class="toggle"></a>' +
    '<span class="title">' + $('#logo').html() + '</span>' +
    '</div>'
)
```

Your titleBar (on small screen) is pulling the html content from your `#logo` element. Check to see that there is indeed a `#logo` element that exists, or change this call to pull a value form another source.

Answer (score 1):

In your `main.js` on line 50 you have this snippet:

```
        // Title Bar.
            $(
                '<div id="titleBar">' +
                    '<a href="#navPanel" class="toggle"></a>' +
                    '<span class="title">' + $('#logo').html() + '</span>' +
                '</div>'
            )
                .appendTo($body);
```

It seems that `$('#logo')` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole document is messy. Go to ToS page and you'll also see Contact anchor.
About "undefined" is that it's always there, it just cannot be seen because it gets

```
display: none;
```

and cannot be seen. Try looking for title class (.title) in titleBar (#titleBar).

Edit: Okay, you guys found the real bug in .js. Good job, I failed haha.